# How do I create task which runs even when the user is logged out? (Pywin32 COM)

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, pywin32

I am new to python COM objects and tried to write a script that creates a scheduled task using the PyWin32 wrapper. The below is what I tried:

I am getting an error that says task doesn't exist. When I went to the Task Scheduler and changed the User, it works. What am I doing wrong here?

```py
import os
import win32com.client

cur_user = os.getlogin()
computer_name = os.environ['COMPUTERNAME']

SCH = win32com.client.Dispatch('Schedule.Service')
SCH.Connect()
root = SCH.GetFolder('\\')

TASK = SCH.NewTask(0)

TriggerType = 2  # Daily

trigger = TASK.Triggers.Create(TriggerType)
starttime = "2023-12-01T13:55:00"  # starts from 1 Dec 8:00
trigger.StartBoundary = starttime
trigger.DaysInterval = 1
trigger.Enabled = True
trigger.Id = "DailyTrigger-8am"

action = TASK.Actions.Create(0)  # 0 refers to the type execute
action.Path = "cmd.exe"
action.Arguments = r'/c start "" "C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\Projects\\Data Transfer\\Current       Files\\ScheduleThis.bat"'
action.ID = "ADTTestPywin32"
action.WorkingDirectory = r"C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\Projects\\Data Transfer\\Current Files"

TASK.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Testing ADT scheduling using pywin32"
TASK.Settings.Enabled = True
TASK.Settings.StopIfGoingOnBatteries = False

task_create_or_update = 6
task_logon_none = 0

TASK.Principal.UserId = cur_user
TASK.Principal.LogonType = 6

root.RegisterTaskDefinition(
    "ADTTestPywin32",
    TASK,
    task_create_or_update,
    cur_user,
    "mypassword",
    task_logon_none 
)
```

Edit: Solved finally. I needed to change the task_logon_none to 1. This ensures that the task runs after logging in with the provided credentials.